# sed / awk / etc - Sorting merged text before paste OR paste special: new line

Tags: command-line, text-processing

**My scenario:**

On an internal platform a list of IPs is displayed like:
`8.8.8.8` `1.0.0.1` `1.1.1.1` `192.168.1.1` `192.168.0.1`

When I copy these values and put them (pasted) in a text file they are all pasted, like:

```
8.8.8.81.0.0.11.1.1192.168.1.1192.168.0.1
```

So practically all are pasted in one line and without spaces.

It is a disaster to copy IP with IP every day when the list can sometimes have thousands of entries.

I have not the slightest idea how this problem can be solved. I tried by inspect element, but each IP is in its own `<span>` element and each span has its own ID and class, so no feasible a mass replace with empty.

**What I need:** Each copied IP should be pasted on a new line.

I use as OS: Ubuntu.

My Shell: ZSH

I am open to any solution.

Comment: Are there any non-printing characters separating the entries? Check with something like `od` or `hexdump`

Comment: if it comes from a web page copy a portion of html code from that page where ips come, and paste an example so community could help. In case its a web page it's better to use scraping tools in a language like python to automate the entire process.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have pdftotext installed on the Ubuntu client?

If not, then start with

```
sudo apt install poppler-utils
```

Then print the web page to a pdf file

to a location such as ~/Downloads/X.pdf

Next with the power of **less**

you can view the text conversion of the PDF file preserving its physical layout:

```
less ~/Downloads/X.pdf
```

and scroll down to the point where the IP addresses reporting occurs.

Try grabbing the list with copy / paste operations to another file.  If that produces an ungarbled format, then you're in luck.

Turning this into an automation can then be driven by using the

**pdftotext** command also installed with the poppler-utils and some grep and sed commands.

```
pdftotext -layout X.pdf X.txt
grep "\." X.txt | sed "s/[[:space:]]/\n/g" | grep [0-9].[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]
```

You should get a result such as

```
8.8.8.8
1.0.0.1
1.1.1.1
192.168.1.1
192.168.0.1
8.8.8.81.0.0.11.1.1192.168.1.1192.168.0.1
```

My X.pdf file was a direct print to PDF of this web page.  Next I ran the above commands that even included the run-together output that you don't want to see.

Perform additional filtering if you need to clean up the output, but this should help you out a lot.

Answer (score 0):

> but each IP is in its own  element and each span has its own ID and class

This suggests that your text is in html file. Try to use html query program [htmlq](https://pypi.org/project/htmlq/). then you can easily extract whatever you need.

to get all the spans and then filter out only ip adresses, something like this should work :

```bash
htmlq -s '\n'  -f yourfile.html 'span' |
  sed -e 's/^<span[^>]*>//' -e 's/<.*//' ) |
  egrep '([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+'
```

You could add `| sort -u` if you need uniq IP and order of appearance in original file does not matter.

Beware that this command will catch everything that looks like an IP within any span. This could be more than what you want and you may have to refine the htmlq query. As you did not paste any example file content, I can't do better than asking for all spans. But hopefully, you can find a more specific selector that will catch only the spans you want.